# Реактивные данные в Android

Tags: java, android

Есть 3 компонента `EditText` и 1 компонент `TextView`.

В `EditText` записываются числа, а в `TextView` сумма данных в `EditText`.

Как сделать компонент `TextView` обновляемым, в зависимости от изменений в `EditText`?

Comment: На EditText-ы вешаются слушатели на изменение ввода, в которых вызывается `textView.setText(<новое значение>)`?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте библиотеки RxJava, RxBinding

```
Observable<Integer> summa = Observable.combineLatest(
            RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(edittext1),
            RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(edittext2),
            RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(edittext3),
            (text1, text2, text3) -> {
                returnt Integer.parseInt(text1) + Integer.parseInt(text2) + Integer.parseInt(text3);
            });

    summa.subscribe(result-> {
        textview.setText(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно вот такое вот решение:

```
EditText editText;
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                //что делать перед изменением текста (получение фокуса)
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                //что делат ьв момент изменения текста. Например, добавлять данные в TextView
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                //что делать после того, как текст изменился (потеря фокуса)
            }
        });
```